# Remove duplicate rows in R, even though in a different order

Tags: r

This feels like it should be obvious but I am really not seeing it!

Here is a mini example of the kind of data I am dealing with:

```
x1 <- as.character(c("Apple", "Banana", "Cat", "Dog", "Orange"))
x2 <- as.character(c("Banana", "Orange", "Dog", "Cat", "Apple"))
x3 <- as.character(c("Orange", "Apple", NA, NA, "Banana"))         
groups <- data_frame(x1, x2, x3)
```

The dataframe has five rows, but in reality, only two are unique - one of them contains three fruits, and the other contains two animals, when reading across the row. The reason there are five rows is because for each fruit or animal, there is a row indicating the other members of their group.

I either want to remove the duplicate rows (I don't care which ones are removed, as long as there is only one row left per group), or alternatively have a group name in a new column, so there are still five rows but with an additional column that goes something like `"Fruit", "Fruit", "Animal", "Animal", "Fruit`. With the second option, I don't really care what the group names are as long as they identify the distinct categories.

I have investigated using `duplicated` (something like `groups[!duplicated(groups$x1), ]`) but obviously that doesn't work because there are no duplicates in any individual column - it's about whether there is anything in that row. There could perhaps be something around ordering rows alphabetically but I'm not sure that is doable - I can't find anything on it (and can't see how it would normally be particualrly helpful...).

My real data has hundreds of rows, so going through manually to identify the groups is not very appealing!

Comment: You may need some kind of key/val matching pair

Comment: Your data has no duplicates, assuming (since this is a `data.frame`) that columns are different. If the columns mean nothing (so that `Dog,Cat` is the same as `Cat,Dog`), then you should probably look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/8989073/3358272

Comment: Yes, the columns are essentially meaningless. It doesn't look like the answers on the link worked for the original questioner, but I'll explore. Getting the impression I will have to find a hacky way round.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if your sample data is giving us the example exactly what you want assistance on, but here is a hack at it. As others in the comments mentioned most of the tools look across rows for unique pairs. If the pairing doesn't matter you could do something like:

```
    library(dplyr)

    x1 <- as.character(c("Apple", "Banana", "Cat", "Dog", "Orange"))
    x2 <- as.character(c("Banana", "Orange", "Dog", "Cat", "Apple"))
    x3 <- as.character(c("Orange", "Apple", NA, NA, "Banana"))         
    groups <- data_frame(x1, x2, x3)

    groups %>% 
       mutate_all(sort, na.last = TRUE) %>% 
       unique()
```

Regardless the unique function will look at unique pairings across rows if the order that they appear in your data does matter. Definitely slow though, and I'm sure that there is something faster. Like something from SQL with SELECT DISTINCT *.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `duplicated` after rearranging the data in a sensible way. One sensible way would be to have `TRUE/FALSE` values for each fruit and animal: instead of `x1` having the value `"dog"`, one would have `dog` having the value `TRUE`. This could be done, for example, like this:

```
g <- na.omit(unique(unlist(groups)))
df <- t(apply(as.matrix(groups), 1, function(x) g %in% x))
# if needed, you could make the `df` human-readable:
df <- setNames(as.data.frame(df), g)
duplicated(df)
```

#### data

```
x1 <- as.character(c("Apple", "Banana", "Cat", "Dog", "Orange"))
x2 <- as.character(c("Banana", "Orange", "Dog", "Cat", "Apple"))
x3 <- as.character(c("Orange", "Apple", NA, NA, "Banana"))         
groups <- data.frame(x1, x2, x3, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```